# removeAt(i) issues with Angular 5 FormArray

Tags: typescript, angular5

After I run this method

```
const control = <FormArray>this.proposalForm.get('proposals');
control.removeAt(i);
```

And then i run this method,

```
addMoreProposals(): void {
    this.proposals.push(this.buildProposals());
    this.computeBalances();
}

computeBalances() {
 let control = this.proposalForm.controls.proposals['controls'}[this.count];
 //console.log(control)
 this.proposalForm.get('proposals.' + this.count + '.ProposedAmount').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
     if (this.count == 0) {
         this.details.CurrentBalance = this.originalBalance - value;
     } else {
         this.details.CurrentBalance = this.latestOutstandingBalance - value
     }
 })
 this.latestOutstandingBalance = this.details.CurrentBalance;
}
```

When I try to run the computeBalances, the ValueChanges return null, since control is now null.

Please, how can I unsuscribe the deleted control so they are available again when I run the addMoreProposals() to dynamically add more forms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a Subscription is declared and destroyed:

```
x: any;
mySub: Subscription;

ngOnInit() {
  this.mySub.subscribe(val => this.x = val); 
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.mySub.unsubscribe();
}
```

Based on your description, the removeAt(i) occurs before computeBalances(). This causes the undefined error.

To prevent this try calling the removeAt inside the subscribe call:

```
this.proposalForm.get('proposals.' + this.count + '.ProposedAmount').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
 if (this.count == 0) {
     this.details.CurrentBalance = this.originalBalance - value;
 } else {
     this.details.CurrentBalance = this.latestOutstandingBalance - value
 }
 //do the removeAt(i) here.
})
```

Comment: Please kindly see my response above. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I see. It looks like the value in .subscribe( value => ... is null.

You can do something like this to UnSubscribe:

`this.logsSub.unsubscribe();`

But it is best to know when you delete the control. It may be deleting it first before computeBalances().

Let me know if you have further questions and additional info.

Comment: Hi, please what is the this.logsSub that i should unsubscribe from? I run computeBalances() when i run addMoreproposals() to add another dynamic formarray. If i did not run removeAt(i), everything will be fine. But once i run the removeAt(i), all my subsequent addMoreProposals() will return control undefined.

Comment: I would assume that your proposalForm is a subscription since you use the .subscribe with it.

`this.proposalForm.get('proposals.' + this.count + '.ProposedAmount').valueChanges.subscribe`

Based on what you describe, the removeAt(i) occurs first, which is why it is causing the undefined error.

To prevent this, do the removeAt(i) inside the .subscribe.

Comment: This is my removeProposalField(i:number) function       
    removeProposalFields(i: number): void {
        const control = <FormArray>this.proposalForm.get('proposals');
        let removedAmount = this.proposalForm.get('proposals').value[i].ProposedAmount;
        this.latestOutstandingBalance = this.details.CurrentBalance + removedAmount;
        control.removeAt(i);
    }                                                                                                                            Do you mean i should make this inside a subcribe ??

Comment: Ah! So control is declared inside the `removeProposalField()` function. I think I now know why you are getting undefined.

Since `const control` is inside `removeProposalField()`, when you click the `addMoreProposals()` button, control is not yet instantiated.

Try declaring `const control` outside and instantiate it outside so that control is accessible to all your functions.

Comment: But I am doing this `get proposals(): FormArray {
        return <FormArray>this.proposalForm.get('proposals');
    }` I thought this intializes it

Comment: its this specific variable - `const control`.

can you post the whole code showing us the removeProposalField() will the rest of the functions?

Comment: kindly find the whole code below. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I think this is resolved now. I put t

```
his.myFormValueChanges$ = this.proposalForm.controls['proposals'].valueChanges;
        this.myFormValueChanges$.subscribe(units => this.updateCalculations(units));
```

in my ngOnInt();

Then I implemented the updateCalculations like this

```
private updateCalculations(units: any) {
        const control = <FormArray>this.proposalForm.controls['proposals'];
        // console.log(units)
        for (let i in units) {
            if (units[i].ProposedAmount != '') {
                if (i == "0") {
                    this.details.CurrentBalance = this.originalBalance - units[i].ProposedAmount;
                }
                else {
                    this.details.CurrentBalance = this.latestOutstandingBalance - units[i].ProposedAmount;
                }
                this.latestOutstandingBalance = this.details.CurrentBalance;
            }



            const endDate = new Date(units[i].EndDate.year, units[i].EndDate.month - 1, units[i].EndDate.day);
            const startDate = new Date(units[i].StartDate.year, units[i].StartDate.month - 1, units[i].StartDate.day);
            let dateDiff = +endDate.getMonth() - +startDate.getMonth();
            let monthDifference = dateDiff + (12 * (endDate.getFullYear() - startDate.getFullYear()));
            let yearDifference = monthDifference / 12;

            if (units[i].PaymentPlan == 1) {
                control.at(+i).get('InstallmentAmount').setValue((units[i].ProposedAmount / (monthDifference / units[i].Frequency)).toFixed(2), { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })
            }

            else if (units[i].PaymentPlan == 2) {
                control.at(+i).get('InstallmentAmount').setValue(((units[i].ProposedAmount) / (monthDifference / (3 * units[i].Frequency))).toFixed(2), { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })

            }
            else if (units[i].PaymentPlan == 3) {
                control.at(+i).get('InstallmentAmount').setValue(((units[i].ProposedAmount) / (yearDifference / (2 * units[i].Frequency))).toFixed(2), { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })
            }

            else if (units[i].PaymentPlan == 4) {
                control.at(+i).get('InstallmentAmount').setValue(((units[i].ProposedAmount) / (yearDifference / units[i].Frequency)).toFixed(2), { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })

            }

            else {
                control.at(+i).get('InstallmentAmount').setValue((units[i].ProposedAmount / units[i].Frequency).toFixed(2), { onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false })

            }

        }
```

Everything is working out fine now. Thanks for your help